# Converter e Validator com injeção CDI

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, ejb, cdi

Alguém consegue injetar CDI ou EJB nos Converter ou Validator em JSF 2.2? Foi dito que a partir do 2.2 seria possível mas eu não estou conseguindo.

Já tentei

```
@EJB
 UserService userService
```

e também

```
@Inject
 UserService userService
```

e ambos não rodaram.

Comment: O que já tentou?

Comment: @Ozelo Seja mais específico, de mais detalhes. Qual container vc está usando, quais são seus arquivos de configuraçã, qual é a versão do Java? Onde foi dito isso? O que vc quer fazer?

Answer (score 3):

O suporte a CDI em [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/FacesConverter.html) e [`Validator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html) está na versão `2.3` do JSF, ainda sem release, apenas *milestones*.

Tal suporte é previsto na [JSR 372](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=372), parte integrante do Java EE 8. Então, você deverá usar dependências ainda não em versão *release* para tal suporte.

Para fazer uso da *milestone*, caso use [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), adicione esta dependência:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-m02</version>
</dependency>
```

Caso não use [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), faça o [download](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.0-m02/) do `JAR` diretamente do repositório.

Feito isto, um exemplo de *converter* seria isto:

```
@RequestScoped
@FacesConverter(value = "customConverter", managed = true)
public class CustomConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private CustomService service;

    // implemente getAsString e getAsObject

}
```

E de *validator*, este:

```
@RequestScoped
@FacesValidator(value = "customValidator", managed = true)
public class CustomValidator implements Validator {

    @Inject
    private CustomService service;

    // implemente validate

}
```

Aqui coloquei escopo de requisição, mas você pode usar os outros suportados também, caso precise.

Perceba que o suporte foi dado ao incluir um novo atributo (`managed`) às já existentes anotações [`@FacesConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/FacesConverter.html) e [`@FacesValidator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/validator/FacesValidator.html).

Este é o suporte *nativo*, ou seja, mesmo não sendo *converter* e *validator* um *bean* gerenciado pelo *container* CDI ele agora é elegível para injeção de dependências.

Uma observação importante é: o *container* deve estar preparado para isto, ou seja, ser compatível com Java EE 8 (ou pelo menos ter o módulo mais recente da implementação JSF), caso contrário, de nada irá adiantar utilizar desta forma. Por exemplo, no Glassfish o suporte ao Java EE 8 é previsto na versão 5. No Glassfish 4 você pode tentar substituir `javax.faces.jar` pela biblioteca JSF 2.3 citada anteriormente.

Em [O que há de novo no JSF 2.3?](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-23/) você pode ver as novidades para o JSF 2.3, verá que algumas das novidades é justamente o aumento do suporte do CDI a mais artefatos do JSF.

P.S.: os links estão da documentação do Java EE 7 por ainda não ter a do Java EE 8.

**Edição**: incluindo formas de usar em versão anterior à `2.3`

Em versão anterior à JSF 2.3, para conseguir fazer uso de CDI você precisará que seu *bean* seja gerenciado pelo *container* para que seja elegível à injeção de dependência, então pode usar por exemplo [`@Named`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Named.html).

Por exemplo, nosso `CustomConverter` ficaria assim:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CustomConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private CustomService service;

    // implemente getAsString e getAsObject

}
```

E nosso `CustomValidator`, assim:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CustomValidator implements Validator {

    @Inject
    private CustomService service;

    // implemente validate

}
```

Também em versão anterior à `2.3`, você pode usar a biblioteca [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/) que dá suporte à CDI, veja o [exemplo](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesValidator) na documentação deles.

Answer (score 1):

Vale apenas ressaltar caso utilize seu converter seja gerenciado por CDI, na pagina XML quando referencias o `converter` tem que ser `converter="{nomebeanconverter}"`, pois apenas com `@FacesConverter` ficaria assim `converter="nomebeanconverter"`